# Calculating minimum finds second lowest instead?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, max, min

Why is the output of this C++ code to find the min and max between inputted elements not showing the lowest number but rather the 2nd to the lowest?
Idk why the min is not working when it is the exact opposite code of the max which is perfectly showing the highest number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array[50], *max, *min, size, i;
    cout<<"Enter the number of elements in array\n";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"Enter array elements\n";
    for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ )
    cin>>array[i];
    max = array;
    min = array;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if (*(array+i) > *max)
        *max = *(array+i);
    }
    cout<<"Maximum element in the array is "<< *max << "\n" ;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    if (*(array+i) < *min)
       *min = *(array+i);
    }
    cout<<"Minimum element in the array is "<< *min <<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `*min = *(array+i);` to `min = array+i;`. Likewise for `*max = *(array+i);`, change to `max = array+i;` Unrelated, both of those for-loops can start at 1, since you're basing initial min/max values on slot-0.

Comment: FYI, the standard library has a [`std::minmax_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) function for this exact purpose, no manual loops needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is a school activity which instructed us to manually code everything. i think this is because so that we could understand it better

Comment: @MaryJhane the main problem with your code is that you are using pointers to determine the min/max elements, without understanding how pointers work. So, unless this is an assignment in learning pointers, stay away from pointers and use values instead, eg: `int max, min; ... max = min = array[0]; for (i = 1; i < size; i++) { if (array[i] > max) max = array[i]; } cout<<max; ... for (i = 1; i < size; i++) { if (array[i] < min) min = array[i]; } cout<<min;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau i also would've used that but it is required in the program that we use i=0 in the for loop

Comment: Concerning _it is required in the program that we use i=0 in the for loop_: That's stupid. ;-) One approach (for your min-max problem and similar things) is to initialize min to the most maximum or an invalid value, max to the most minimum. More clever is, to assign both to the first array value. (For an array of length 1, this would be the final answer.) In this case, the first element (with index 0) doesn't need to be checked anymore. (The check is not wrong but useless.) Hence, `for (i = 1;`...

Comment: Though, that's the minor issue. The major issue is whether it's required that `min` and `max` have to be of type `int*` (i.e. a pointer). It would be much simpler (for you) if you would make them of type `int` (i.e. a value).